# Check if user is logged in or not using firebase in react

Tags: reactjs, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I do have a `react` with `firebase` project. So I successfully able to login the user via `firebase` authentication. What I want to do is to set the user details in all pages. I thought, I can able to access the user variables in react everywhere like laravel's `Auth::user()` . But I tried in so many ways to achieve that. But I couldn't able to get the user details in another page. Is there any way to get the user details in another page ?

My `signin.js` page .

```
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user) => {
      alert("login success")
      console.log(user.user)
      this.setState({uid:user.user.uid})
      localStorage.setItem('uid',JSON.stringify(user.user))
      window.location.assign('/')
      }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.code)
            alert(error.message)
        })
      }
```

My `dashboard.js` page where I want to access user variables .

```
  componentDidMount() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('uid')){
      //alert("welcome"+localStorage.getItem('uid'));
      this.setState({user : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('uid'))})
      console.log("this : "+localStorage.getItem('uid'))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

if (user != null) {
  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
  uid = user.uid;  // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
                   // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
                   // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
```

you can use `currentUser` method on `firebase.auth()` callback to fetch user details.
If you are signing in using frontend firebase package then this is no issue, whether you call this on the same page or any other page

Comment: Do I need to import firebase ?

Comment: It didn't help. However When I'm surfing around firebase documentation , I found out that , `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged()`  which helped me to identify the user. . But is there any other simple way to do it /

Comment: I am sorry, i didn't get you. You have already imported firebase isn't it?

Comment: onAuthStateChanged is for checking whether the auth state is changed. It won't give you user details it seems. You import firebase (and only firebase) on the page were you want the user details and call the method i mentioned

Comment: The problem is currentUser() is not returning the user variable. It store it as null

Comment: Note: `currentUser` might also be null because the `auth` object has not finished initializing. If you use an `observer` to keep track of the user's sign-in status, you don't need to handle this case. . What does it means ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200930/discussion-between-kevin-red-and-farooq).

Answer (score 1):

Hi I'm pretty sure why this is happening as firebase autologin functionality which handles logging you in to your firebase account is not fast, from my experience it takes anywhere from 0.5-2 seconds to fill in the auth state, and by the time your page checks auth.currentUser it doesn't get any as the login is not complete yet.

SOLUTION

on your dashboard page, have an onAuthStateChange function at mount and don't worry about it working only on auth state change, it would run everytime your dashboard is mounted and then the user object from that